# Grab Answer Key from Short Answer Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am attempting to grab the answer key from the short answer in Google forms.

I am attempting to grab the following answer key from a short answer question (refer to the screenshot below). Below the Short answer text, it shows you the correct answer.
[image]

However, when reading the documentation, there seems there is no way to do so. Is there an alternative way to grab the answer key from the short answer in Google Forms?

The following is the script I am using to grab the information from the quiz:

```
function extractFormData(fullNme) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var quizAdded = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  var uniqueQuizID = Utilities.getUuid(), question_listID = uniqueQuizID.concat("-questions");
  var constructedJSON = {};
  var answer_val = false;
  var errorJSON = {};
  var email = form.getEditors()[0].getEmail();

  var quizInfo = {
    "quiz_name": form.getTitle(),
    "quiz_owner": fullNme,
    "quiz_description": form.getDescription(),
    "quiz_owner_email": email,
    "quiz_submited_date":quizAdded
  };

  //console.log(JSON.stringify(quizInfo));
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    switch(item.getType()) {
      case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
        var question = item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
        var ques = question.getTitle();
        var question_type = "Multiple Choice";
        var optns = [];
        var answr;
        var answers = question.getChoices();
        answer_val = false;
         for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
          var clean = answers[j].getValue();
          optns.push(clean);
          if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
            answr = answers[j].getValue();
            for(var x = 0; x < optns.length; x++){
                if(answr == optns[x]){
                  answer_val = true;
                  break;
                }
            }
          }
        }
        var multiJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        constructedJSON[i+1] = multiJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
        var question = item.asCheckboxItem();
        var ques = question.getTitle();
        var question_type = "CheckBox";
        var optns = [];
        var answr = [];
        var answers = question.getChoices();
        
         for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
          var clean = answers[j].getValue();
          optns.push(clean);
          if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
            answr.push(answers[j].getValue());
          }
        }
        var checkJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        constructedJSON[i+1] = checkJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
        var question = item.asParagraphTextItem();
        var ques = question.getTitle();
        var question_type = "free response";
        var optns = [];
        var answr;
        var paraJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        constructedJSON[i+1] = paraJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
        var question = item.asTextItem();
        var ques = question.getTitle();
        var question_type = "free response";
        var optns = "";
        var answr = "";
        var textJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        constructedJSON[i+1] = textJSON;
        break;
    }

    if(!answer_val){
      errorJSON = {"Question":ques, "Options":optns, "Answer": answr, "Sucess": false};
      //error(ques);
      break; 
    }
  }

  if(answer_val){
     notifyUser();  
  } else {
    return errorJSON;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the answer key from the short answer in Google forms`. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike: I have updated my question. Hope it clarifies what I am looking for

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to retrieve the correct answers of the question? Or you want to retrieve the points of the question?

Comment: @Tanaike: The goal is to retrieve the correct answer to the question. I am able to do that with multiple-choice and checkboxes. But for short answers, I am not able to.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike: I am able to retrieve a question-answer if it is multiple-choice or a checkbox. However, if the type of question is a short answer, then I am not able to retrieve the answer

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for the inconvenience. About `I am able to retrieve a question-answer if it is multiple-choice or a checkbox. However, if the type of question is a short answer, then I am not able to retrieve the answer`, when I tested this, unfortunately, I can retrieve the correct answer from the short answer. So, I cannot replicate your situation. I'm worried that I might misunderstand your `short answer`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: In order to correctly replicate your `I am able to retrieve a question-answer if it is multiple-choice or a checkbox. However, if the type of question is a short answer, then I am not able to retrieve the answer`, can you provide the detailed information for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Can you share the script you are using as well? @RobertoFlores

Comment: @Tanaike: I have added the script that I am using. I hope it clears what I am attempting to do

Comment: @ale13 I have added the script as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I asked for the information to correctly understand your `I am able to retrieve a question-answer if it is multiple-choice or a checkbox. However, if the type of question is a short answer, then I am not able to retrieve the answer`. From your added information, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. Because when I tested my answer, the correct answer can be retrieved. I have to deeply apologize for this again. So can you provide the sample Google Form for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike: If you take a look at the screenshot provided, I am not able to retrieve the answer key if the type of question is a short answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. From `If you take a look at the screenshot provided, I am not able to retrieve the answer key if the type of question is a short answer.`, unfortunately, when I tested my answer, the correct answer can be retrieved. So, I'm worried that my tested sample might be different from yours. I have to deeply apologize for this again. So, in order to correctly understand your current issue, I asked about the sample Google Form. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike: sorry. Let me explain better. The short answer is a TextItem: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item. Per the documentation, there doesn't seem like a way to grab the answer key.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The short answer is a TextItem: developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item. Per the documentation, there doesn't seem like a way to grab the answer key.`, it's yes. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for retrieving the correct answers using Form Service (FormApp). So I had proposed to use Google Forms API which has been released recently. I deeply apologize that I proposed to use Google Forms API.

Comment: But when I proposed a sample script using Google Forms API, in your reply, you said `I am able to retrieve a question-answer if it is multiple-choice or a checkbox. However, if the type of question is a short answer, then I am not able to retrieve the answer`. So I asked about the sample Google Form for correctly replicating it. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike: I am reading over the documentation and not quite understanding how it works

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I'm confused by your reply of `I am reading over the documentation and not quite understanding how it works`. From your reply of `I am able to retrieve a question-answer if it is multiple-choice or a checkbox. However, if the type of question is a short answer, then I am not able to retrieve the answer`, I had thought that you said by testing my proposed script. So I asked your Google Form to correctly replicate it. I would like to correctly understand your current situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike: Sorry, let me explain. What I meant is I am reading over your proposed solution of using Google Form API. Attempting to translate the example you provided and incorporate in what I have

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, you had still not tested my proposed script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: From your proposed script, no. Trying to first understand how it works and adjust it to what I have

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand your current situation. When you tested my proposed script and my script was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1):

**The method that you are looking for is not yet supported in Apps Script.**

*Therefore, you have two options in this situation:*

1. Create a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) and provide all the necessary details.
2. Make use of Forms API by using the Forms API advanced service in Apps Script and try Tanaike's proposed solution.

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms#correctanswers), you can see that resources of type `CorrectAnswer` have a field available:

```
{
  "value": string
}
```

> A single correct answer for a question. For multiple-valued (CHECKBOX) questions, several CorrectAnswers may be needed to represent a single correct response option.

#### Reference

- [Forms API](https://developers.google.com/forms/api).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the correct answer from each question of Google Form using Google Apps Script.

In this case, when I checked the method for directly achieving your goal using Google Form service (FormApp), unfortunately, I couldn't find it. But fortunately, I confirmed that when Google Forms API is used, your goal can be achieved. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using Google Forms API.

### Usage:

#### 1. Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE.

In order to use Forms API, please link Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE, and please enable Forms API at API console. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE)

#### 2. Sample script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const formId = "###"; // Please set your Google Form ID.
  const url = "https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/" + formId + "?fields=*";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const values = obj.items.map(({ title, questionItem }) => (
    { title, point: questionItem.question.grading.pointValue, answer: questionItem.question.grading.correctAnswers ? questionItem.question.grading.correctAnswers.answers.map(({ value }) => value) : [] }
  ));
  console.log(values)
}
```

- In this script, please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body.readonly`.

#### 3. Testing.

When this script is run to the Google Form, the following sample value is obtained.

```json
[
  {"title":"sample question 1","point":5,"answer":["sample1","sample2"]},
  {"title":"sample question 2","point":3,"answer":["Option 2","Option 3"]},
  {"title":"sample question 3","point":3,"answer":["Option 2"]}
]
```

- This is a sample value.

### Note:

- **When you want to simply check this, you can also use ["Try this method" of Forms API](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/get).**
- When the correct answer is not set, an error occurred. So I modified it. By this, when the correct answer is not set, `[]` is returned.

### References:

- [Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE)
- [Method: forms.get](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/get)